# Unable to locate package python-pip

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I am running Debian 9 and I want to install python pip but there is an error:

`E: Unable to locate package python-pip`

I've tried sudo `apt-get update && sudo apt-get python-pip`, but I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

The command to install software with `apt` is

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

You missed the `install` command to `apt-get`.

Comment: Missing `install` should print `E: Invalid operation python-pip` error.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `sources.list` (as root):

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

with the following lines:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

<kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> , <kbd>Enter</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> to save , then run:

```
apt update
apt install python-pip
```

[Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)

[Package: python-pip](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/python-pip/download)